# Test for underlying bias in a type of lottery

Tags: probability, statistics

A lottery issues $N$ tickets without replacement, and awards each ticket a pre-determined payoff $(0,...,p)$. Both *N* and the *Np* are fixed. For example, they sell $300$ tickets and $5$ of them award $25$.

How would one go about testing for bias in this case (i.e. comparing expected values to observed ones)? Would chi-square be robust enough?

I'm just trying to determine if it would be any different than standard lotteries with situations like $$\binom{49}{6},$$ which feature concrete probabilities aligned with payoffs. Thanks